# App Center - Mobile site not passing oauth code

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-apps

I'm trying to set up my app for the App Center and have come across an issue on the mobile site preview.

For the main Website preview Facebook is passing the code auth token parameter in the query string as expected. I am using this to login the user and display a personalized experience as they ask for in the guidelines.

However on the Mobile Web site Facebook is not passing this parameter after authentication. The only alternative seems to be to use the Javascript SDK to automatically login the user.

I've also noticed that on the preview page the Website version links directly to my website whereas the Mobile preview links to the m.facebook.com/apps URL, though they should be set up the same.

Comment: is this still a problem for you? did you file a bug report? (If so, please link to the bug here)

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem, but with the very Website option, as I don't use the mobile one. As a matter of fact, I have never seen the code in the query parameters coming directly from the app center, and I have been doing this for quite a while.